# Solve by means of regular perturbation to obtain an approximate solution up to and including $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$

Tags: numerical-methods, perturbation-theory

> I have to solve the following ODEs:
>
> 1. $y''+ y = e^{\epsilon \cos x}$, $y(0,\epsilon)=y(1,\epsilon)=0$;
> 2. $y''+ y = \epsilon y^2$, $y(0,\epsilon)=1$, $y'(0,\epsilon)=0$.

---

I am having trouble with these two questions.

For the first one, I got:
\begin{align}
y''_0 + y_0 &=1,& y_0(0)&=y_0(1)=0\\
y''_1 + y_1 &= \cos x,& y_1(0)&=y_1(1)=0
\end{align}
Not sure where the $\cos x$ is from.

For the second question, unsure how $y_0(x)=\cos x$
and $y_1(x)=1/2-1/3(\cos x)-1/6(\cos 2x)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

1. ) You can write the right side as series expansion in $ϵ$, that is, insert the series for the exponential function
   $$
   e^{ϵ\cos x}=1+ϵ\cos x+\frac{ϵ^2}2\cos^2 x+\frac{ϵ^3}6\cos^2 x+...
   $$
2. ) The initial equation is the harmonic oscillator
   $$
   y_0''+y_0=0,~~y_0(0)=1,~~y_0'(0)=0 
   $$
   which has $y_0(x)=\cos(x)$ as solution. The next equation of the terms of first order in $ϵ$ is
   $$
   y_1''+y_1=y_0^2,~~y_1(0)=1,~~y_1'(0)=0 
   $$
   and $\cos^2x$ is as is well-known equal to $\frac12(1+\cos(2x))$. Apply the method of undetermined coefficients to find the corresponding particular solution.

Comment: solving y''+y=0 gives me: c1cos(x)+c2sin(x)

and solving for the particular integral: substituting acos(x)+bsin(x) back into the ODE:

y= acos(x)+bsin(x)
y'=-asin(x)+bcos(x)
y''=-acos(x)-bsin(x)
plugging this into the ODE would just cancel and leave 0=cos(x)

So, how does the solution give y=1/2sin(x)

Comment: Now apply variation of constants or undetermined coefficients to find a particular solution for the right side $1$.